# meteor iron router basic example. Can't make it route

Tags: meteor, iron-router

I simply created a meteor project and copy/paste from the example 'basic' files (found at https://github.com/EventedMind/iron-router/tree/devel/examples/basic) replacing Meteor project .html and .js files.

On the HTML, the example failed to include any template inclusion so I added {{> Home}} and run Meteor between the 'body' block.

```
<body>
 {{> Home}}
</body>
```

The complete HTML code is:
    
      basic

```
<body>
{{> Home}}
</body>

<template name="Home">
  <h1>Home</h1>
    {{> Nav}}
  <p>
    Data Title: {{title}}
  </p>
</template>

<template name="One">
  <h1>Page One</h1>
   {{> Nav}}
</template>

<template name="Two">
  {{> Nav}}

  <h1>Page Two</h1>
</template>

 <template name="Nav">
  <ul>
    <li>
  <a href="/">Home</a>
    </li>
    <li>
  <a href="/One">Page One</a>
</li>
<li>
  <a href="/Two">Page Two</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</template>
```

The .js code is exactly as in the example.

When run, however, it failed to change or route to pages One and Two. It simply stays on Home.

I am learning to work with it but I don't seem to get it right even on the simplest of examples. What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Router.map is now deprecated and replaced by Router.route, however, there seem to be a few bugs they're still ironing out. First of all, I've found that their basic routing function rarely works at the moment, so don't use it for now, i.e.:

```
Router.route('/path', function() {
  this.render('pathName');
});
```

Whether this is due to compatibility issues or something else, I have no idea.  I have found a very standard formula that seems to work quite nicely however, and that is to replace the function with the built in "Route Specific Options", and specify exactly what you want, like so using basic JSON:

```
Router.route('/path', {
  name: 'pathName',
  path: '/path',
  template: 'templateName',
  data: function () {
    title: 'My Title'
  }
});
```

Notice the path: option.  This should not be necessary, as the path is defined as the first parameter of your Router function, but they specifically state in the documentation that you may need to include a path: in your routes for backwards compatibility.  I'm sure once they get everything operating smoothly you'll be able to delete this entirely.

Also, the template: option should not be necessary if the templateName is the same as your /path (and for that matter, the pathName: option should not be necessary if it is also the same as your /path), but I've found including them just makes life easier as sometimes they will not function properly otherwise.

In short, when the bugs are gone, simple templates like yours will be called with one line:

```
Router.route('/one');
```

The end result is that they have simplified how routes are called and defined, but unfortunately, it just doesn't seem to working as planned at the moment.  I hope this helps you with understanding the difference between Router.map and Router.route now.

Plus, the main problem with your code before was that you inserted the partial {{> Home}} between your body tag, which isn't necessary and messes things up, as that partial will always remain even as meteor attempts to route between and load other templates.  In essence, when Meteor went to load template "One" it had to do so on top of template "Home", meaning you had, among other things, two {{> Nav}} partials loading at once.

Comment: Dear jeremiah, I think you nailed it. Router.route now works with your suggestion. I would have never figured out, specially being a newcomer. However, I noticed that the data "My Title" did not come across and haven't been shown on the page. Could that be yet a another bug?

Comment: Here's a great link to help you learn about data contexts and how they operate: https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/a-guide-to-meteor-templates-data-contexts/

Answer (score 0):

When using iron router package you must leave body tag as it is or don't include it at all, i'm using a layout template but its not necessary:

basic.html:

```
<head>
    <title>basic</title>
</head>

<body>
</body>

<template name="layout">
    {{> yield}} 
</template>

<template name="Home">
    {{> Nav}}

    <h1>Home</h1>

    <p>
        Data Title: {{title}}
    </p>
</template>

<template name="One">
    {{> Nav}}

    <h1>Page One</h1>
</template>

<template name="Two">
    {{> Nav}}

 <h1>Page Two</h1>
</template>

<template name="Nav">
    <ul>
        <li>
            <a href="/">Home</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/one">Page One</a>
        </li>
        <li>
            <a href="/two">Page Two</a>
        </li>
    </ul>
</template>
```

basic.js:

```
Router.configure({
    layoutTemplate: 'layout'
});

Router.map(function(){
    this.route('Home', {path: '/', data: {title: 'My title'}});
    this.route('One');
    this.route('Two');
});
```

and now works properly.

Comment: Hi Chreyes. Thanks! It worked when I change from "Router.route" as it is in the example to Route.map in your code. Which one is right? However, it is not rendering the page One and Two. We can see it routes there but the page shows completely blank.

Comment: Hi Chreyes. Forget my last comment... made a silly mistake and it is now working just fine! Thank you very much!!! I will try to leaner the difference between Route.map and Route.routr. Your support already helped me a lot!

Comment: Soory.. I can't vote up. Need to improve reputation.

Comment: The map function say: convert `Router.map(function(){
    this.route('Home', {path: '/'});});` to `Router.route('Home', {path: '/'});` in this case.